# Heroku not using cache for Yarn v3

Tags: heroku, yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces, yarnpkg-v2, yarnpkg-v3

Trying to get Heroku to use cached modules for Yarn v3 using workspaces. I have the following:

`package.json`:

```
"engines": {
    "node": "16.x",
    "yarn": "3.x"
  },
  "cacheDirectories": [
    "node_modules",
    "packages/components/node_modules",
    "packages/lib/node_modules",
    "packages/schema/node_modules",
    "packages/web/node_modules",
    "packages/web/.next/cache"
  ]
```

`heroku-buildpack-features`:

```
cache-native-yarn-cache=true
```

Heroku output:

```
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       USE_YARN_CACHE=true
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
        !     You don't need to specify Yarn engine. Heroku will install the latest Yarn 1.x, so that per project version can be used. More information here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#global-install
              https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
       
       engines.node (package.json):  16.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.7.0...
       Using default npm version: 7.20.3
       Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.11)
       Using yarn 3.0.0

-----> Installing binaries
        !     You don't need to specify Yarn engine. Heroku will install the latest Yarn 1.x, so that per project version can be used. More information here: https://yarnpkg.com/getting-started/install#global-install
              https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support
       
       engines.node (package.json):  16.x
       engines.npm (package.json):   unspecified (use default)
       engines.yarn (package.json):  unspecified (use default)
       
       Resolving node version 16.x...
       Downloading and installing node 16.7.0...
       Using default npm version: 7.20.3
       Resolving yarn version 1.22.x...
       Downloading and installing yarn (1.22.11)
       Using yarn 3.0.0
       
-----> Restoring cache
       Loading 6 from cacheDirectories (package.json):
       - node_modules
       - packages/components/node_modules (not cached - skipping)
       - packages/lib/node_modules
       - packages/schema/node_modules
       - packages/web/node_modules
       - packages/web/.next/cache

<a bunch of resolve stuff>

       ➤ YN0000: ┌ Fetch step
       ➤ YN0013: │ @apollo/client@npm:3.4.7 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry
       ➤ YN0013: │ @apollo/protobufjs@npm:1.2.2 can't be found in the cache and will be fetched from the remote registry

<and so on>
```

I've tried adding `".yarn/cache"` to `cacheDirectories` in `package.json`, but it always says it's empty.

Not really sure where to go from here.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As of 9/2/2021, Heroku's nodeJS buildback doesn't fully support yarn 2. They started adding support in [v173](https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md#v173-2020-07-16), but caching hasn't been fully addressed yet.

The underlying issue is that the buildpack doesn't properly detect that `$BUILD_DIR/.yarn/cache` exists and sets the environment variable `YARN_CACHE_FOLDER` to something other than `.yarn/cache`.(see
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/752f1d5a139a800920cf5bb1bf70aad1a2954525/bin/compile#L140)

When the buildpack gets to the cache step the `.yarn/cache` directory doesn't actually exist.

### The solution:

I was able to work around this by manually setting `YARN_CACHE_FOLDER` to `.yarn/cache` in the [config vars](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#managing-config-vars). You can do this via the CLI by running `heroku config:set YARN_CACHE_FOLDER=.yarn/cache`.

Ensure you also have `.yarn/cache` listed in [`cacheDirectories`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#custom-caching).

You will know it works when the build logs show:

```
-----> Caching build
       Saving 1 cacheDirectories (package.json):
       - .yarn/cache
```

If it did not work there would be a `(nothing to cache)` note next to `.yarn/cache`.

Comment: Woo hoo! Works great, good find. Much thanks!

Comment: Hmm... almost: it works for installing dev dependencies, but not when pruning `devDependencies`. It's still progress, but would be great if prune also ran with cache. Perhaps it's this line? https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-nodejs/blob/5b3fac93c1d08c025620112b6cb479ee46a0db1f/lib/dependencies.sh#L183. Not quite sure how to get around it.